# How can I get the role name

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php
    $role_class = new RoleModel;
    $role_name = "";
    foreach ($role_class->getInfoById("role_id") as $row) {
        # code...
        $role_name = $row->role_name;
    }
?>
<fieldset class="g12 go pb_s">
    <legend>Basic Info</legend>
    <div class="g12 go">
        <div class="g7 go">
            <div class="g2">
                <label for="groupName">Role Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="g4">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type Role Name here..." name="role_name" value="<?php echo $role_name; ?>" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please share some more code you have done so far

Comment: public function getInfoById($role_id){

  $role_id = $this->db->escape_str($role_id);

  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->where("role_id=",$role_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('roles');

  return $query->result();

 }

Comment: $role_class = new RoleModel;

                                

                                foreach ($role_class->getRoleList() as $row){ 

                                        ?>
                                <tr id="<?php echo $row->role_id; ?>">
                                <td class="center">
                                        <?php
                                            echo $row->role_name;
                                        ?>
                                </td>

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's $post to retrieve the value of the input tag via the name of the HTML tag.

For Example, change the method in your form and then echo out the value by the name of the input:

In your Html

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="role_name" id="role_name" value="<?php echo $role_name;?>">
</form>
```

In your .php, you can get the value like below

```
$role_name=$post['role_name'];
```

Since the editor edited his questions, i will add more example.

For example, i got a list of data want to show in the html, in controller, i will put into an array first.

```
  $form_fields = array('username', 'ref', 'password', 'password_confirm')
```

after that in html, i will do like this

```
<?php foreach($__form_fields as $field) {?>
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $field?>" name="<?php echo $field? >" value="" required="required">
<?php }?>
```

which the above code will loop and the input field will have he name

Comment: Tom, do you mean that u have a list of data and want to show in the select list of dropdown?